# CSS Matrix causes alignment issues

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created an HTML container with curved edges on 3 sides using the CSS transform matrix. But when I try to add text or images, they are either in the opposite direction (image) or flipped horizontally (text).

```html
<div class="review">
  <img src="/src/images/tina.jpg" alt="tina" class="review__avatar" />
  <p class="fw-500">TINA FRANCIS</p>
</div>
```

The styles are

```
.review {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 75px 75px 75px 0px;
  transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

  &__avatar {
    width: 90px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
  }
}
```

Any way to fix this?

### Code preview using generated code and missing image to show live demonstration of the issue.

```css
.review {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 75px 75px 75px 0px;
  transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.review__avatar {
  width: 90px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="review">
  <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/69.jpg" alt="tina" class="review__avatar" />
  <p class="fw-500">TINA FRANCIS</p>
</div>
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve
[image: review]

Comment: What basically do you want by transforming it?

Comment: So you want the avatar and text to go on right side without them getting flipped? Is that it? If so, you don't need to use transforms.

Comment: Is there still a way to get the curves without getting flipped?

Comment: This is not your full code. That `matrix` come from `PS` or `AI`. You can't use that `transform` property. Remove `transform: matrix` use position `absolute` or use `flexbox` to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to use transform . 
You can just use `border-radius: 75px 75px 0px 75px;`

Full code :

```
.review {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 75px 75px 0px 75px;
  border: 1px solid red; 
  padding:20px; 
}
.review__avatar {
  width: 90px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}



<div class="review">
  <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/69.jpg" alt="tina" class="review__avatar" />
  <p class="fw-500">TINA FRANCIS</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.review {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 75px 75px 75px 0px;
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 25px;
}
.review__avatar {
  width: 90px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.background {
  padding:10px;
  background-color: red;    
}
```

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="review">
        <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/69.jpg" alt="tina"            class="review__avatar" />
        <p class="fw-500">TINA FRANCIS</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this, this will help you. There was a problem with your transform.

Answer (score 0):

You no need to use transform property achieve your goal. Below is the full `HTML` and `CSS` code. Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/MWwNVpy).

**HTML**

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="review">
      <span>
        <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/69.jpg" alt="tina"            class="review__avatar" />
      </span>
      <p class="fw-500">TINA FRANCIS</p>
    </div>
  <div class="review-text">
    <h5>Love it</h5>
    <span>*****</span>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.background{
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 75px 75px 0 75px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.review{
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.review__avatar{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 90px;
}
.review-text{
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
.review-text h5{
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.review-text span{
  color: yellow;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
}
.review-text p{
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.25;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.background{
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 75px 75px 0 75px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.review{
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.review__avatar{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 90px;
}
.review-text{
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
.review-text h5{
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.review-text span{
  color: yellow;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
}
.review-text p{
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.25;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
    <div class="review">
      <span>
        <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/69.jpg" alt="tina"            class="review__avatar" />
      </span>
      <p class="fw-500">TINA FRANCIS</p>
    </div>
  <div class="review-text">
    <h5>Love it</h5>
    <span>*****</span>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]